# Why "What were you doing?"

Tags: tense

[This is the clip blowing up the elevator from The Matrix (1999)](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/an-WZsCtmm4Yh774/the_matrix_1999_blowing_up_the_elevator/).

> *Agent Brown and Agent Jones walk back into the office where Agent Smith is 'questioning' Morpheus.*
>
> *Agent Smith stands up hastily and looks shocked by their sudden entry.*
>
> Agent Jones : What were you doing?!
>
> Agent Brown : He doesn't know (what's going on outside)...
>
> Agent Smith : Know what?
>
> *Agent Smith plugs his earpiece back in, and looks at the other two agents.*

I wonder whether he can say "What did you do?" or "What have you done?" instead in this particular situation?

"What were you doing?" implies it is a process in which something is clearly or implictly stated.(like, I was reading a book when it **began to rain**. I was reading it **at six**), but I cannot find an implicit signifying thing here.

Comment: Can you edit to explain the context? I'm at work and can't view the clip so I don't know what you mean by "this particular situation". (We also try on StackExchange sites to make things clear just from the question or answer alone, to protect against link rot.)

Comment: It is done. @starsplusplus

Comment: From the script you've given, I'd say that the implicit statement would be something like, "What were you doing [just now]?" or "What were you doing [before you came in]?"

Comment: If I remember it correctly, in the movie it was like, "What were you doing (while they were invading us)?" [Neo and Trinity came to rescue Morpheus.] With a subtext, "So you haven't known what was going on!"

Comment: That is possible, but it cannot explain why Agent Jones shows his surprise at the way Agent Smith is 'questioning' Morpheus. @Damkerng T.

Comment: Again, from my vague memory (I couldn't watch the video at the moment), I believe that all agents are expected to be in contact at all time. However, Agent Smith disconnected his earphones when he was interrogating Morpheus (and Neo and Trinity came to the building just after his unplugging)--so Agent Jones's surprise is reasonable because presumably Agent Smith should have already known what was going on.

Comment: I agree. The movie is extremely complicated. Viewers have various opinions on every slight part of it. @Damkerng T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two in the room were doing something, but the two walking in were not aware what that was.

So when they walk in they ask what it was the people (or one of them) in the room were doing.

If they would ask *What did you do?* or *What have you done?*, this would imply that they did not walk in on an ongoing action (like talking, or interrogating), but that they notice that something has happened (which has now finished, but the evidence of which is present).

Both those options would apply is one of the people in the room would appear to be dead when the two men enter.

> *man enters room, sees other man and an unmoving body*
>   What did you do! Why did you kill him!?
>   Don't worry, he's not dead. Just unconscious.

Since the assumption in the movie is that whatever the men were doing in the room was an *ongoing* activity, the question is not posed as if a completed action is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in the context you mention *what were you doing fits perfectly*, I presume that these guys stop their activity when they see the police. So it refers to a continuos action in the past.

Comment: I know it fits, but I was considering the other three options.

Comment: The other options imply different contexts. That they are doing something the moment the police arrive, or did something sometime in the past. What have you done is not so effective as the continuos form here,I think.

Comment: Why not "what did you do just now?"? @Josh61

Comment: It doesn't sound correct, does it?

Comment: Why is that? This also represents a past event. @Josh61

Comment: Yes, but with 'just now' I'd use what have you done!! Not a past tense.

Comment: Not in AmE, I think. Do you speak BrE?

Comment: I see your point.. Nonetheless  I think 'what were you doing' is the best choice' .. The rest is up to you !

Comment: It indeed is the best choice, but I am thinking about what the others would mean in this context.

Comment: Read  my notes again pls.

Comment: @Josh61 - Actually, you should probably incorporate your "notes" into your answer. It would be better for everyone if you elaborated up there than down here.